# $(a+b) \cdot (a-b)=a^2-b^2, \forall a,b \in R \text{ iff R is commutative }$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Let $R$ a ring. Show that $(a+b) \cdot (a-b)=a^2-b^2, \forall a,b \in R \text{ iff R is commutative }$.

That's what I have tried:

$$(a+b) \cdot (a-b)=a^2-b^2 \Rightarrow a \cdot a+a(-b)+ba+b(-b)=a^2-b^2 \Rightarrow a^2-ab+ba-b^2=  a^2-b^2 \Rightarrow -ab+ba=0_R \Rightarrow ba=ab, \text{ so R is commutative}$$

Could you tell me if it is right??

Comment: Yes, it is right...and the other direction?

Comment: @DonAntonio How can I show the other direction???

Comment: @evinda , read my answer.

Comment: Actually you should replace all your $\Rightarrow$ to $\iff$. It is a valid proof

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\;R\;$ is commutative then

$$(a-b)(a+b)=a^2+\overbrace{ab-ba}^{=0\;, \text{ by comm.!}}-b^2=a^2-b^2$$

Comment: I understand..Thank you very much!!!